# How to create pkpass file dynamically in java?

Tags: java, dynamic, wallet, apple-wallet, pkpass

I am integrating Apple wallet functionality in my website.

As I understood, we have to create the .pkpass file from pass.json, signature and manifest.json...etc .
But this is for static coupon, but i am generating the coupon  / pass dynamically and want to create the .pkpass file also dynamically based on the customer details. I will create different coupon for different customers and should generate the .pkpass file.

How can this be done?  How can I create a .pkpass file dynamically for a each row on click of an "Add to Apple wallet" button? is there any thirdparty service available?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not aware of any Java libraries that handle the pass compilation, but we have a third party service at [passkit.com](https://passkit.com) and a Java SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [jpasskit](https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit) library which is a opensource library available in github for Java. You can add the Jpasskit library to your springboot application via maven dependency, as below,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.brendamour</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpasskit</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also you can follow the below step by step procedure to get the dynamic passes in Java by Rest API using Springboot frame work as described in the [medium](https://medium.com/@mumtazparbhin/create-rest-api-to-download-apple-wallet-pkpass-file-using-spring-java-bd66e4eb8f3e) article.

https://medium.com/@mumtazparbhin/create-rest-api-to-download-apple-wallet-pkpass-file-using-spring-java-bd66e4eb8f3e